# DataTables Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'pdfMake' of undefined

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm attempting to set up Datatables for a table.  There is nothing particularly unusual about the table (content has been left blank in this example), and I believe I have included all the correct files for Datatables to function, however, there is an javascript error:

buttons.html5.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'pdfMake' of undefined

```
   <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Buttons-1.5.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Buttons-1.5.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/pdfmake-0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Buttons-1.5.4/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Responsive-2.2.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/Buttons-1.5.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/DataTables-1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/Responsive-2.2.2/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body><table id="termtable7"></table></body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var datatable=$('#termtable'+question_id).DataTable({        
       dom:'Bfrtip',
       buttons:['columnsToggle', 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'],
      responsive:true
    });
});
</script>
```

The only buttons that are displayed are the columnsToggle and the search option.  The other buttons are missing due to the error.

Would anyone have an understanding of Datatables that could clue me in on what is really going on here?

Comment: As the error refers to pdfmake, I wonder if it's not related to the datatable and instead it's having issues with `pdfmake.min.js`.  You can test this by commenting out that `<script>` tag

Comment: This did nothing.  It seems to be getting caught up in buttons.html5.min.js at v.Buttons.pdfMake=function(a)

Answer (score 14):

Probably it is late to answer this question but might help someone else..

I had to change my loading order to following and error went away. Pay attention to what loading order of javascript files. Order has to be exactly same order otherwise components are not going to be found.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>   
<script src="js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks - this was tons of help! Note you still need dataTables.buttons.min.js when using the html5 buttons (as shown above). This threw me off too.

Comment: its help me lot :)